# How do I pass in url parameter using request.get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Actual api should be like below:

```
https://.../api/v1/users/getprofile?access_token={{access_token}}
```

Below is how I am trying to call the API using `request`

```
 const request = require('request'); 



request.get("https://.../api/v1/users/getProfile?accessToken=",{accessToken: req.query.accessToken})
```

However, it failed. How can I print out whats the url being called ? And how can I fix the error ?

Comment: Encode the URL before passing, using encodeURI() https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: And this code are you using on server side? In the backend? Or in the client, in some Vue component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this.

```
const request = require("request")
request.get({url: "http://.../api/v1/users/getprofile", qs: {"accessToken": "xxxxx"}}, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(err, body);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    const request = require('request'); 

    try {
        var strURI = encodeURI("https://.../api/v1/users/getProfile?accessToken=");
        request.get(strURI, {accessToken: req.query.accessToken});
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Exception: " + e.message);
    }
```

Comment: how can i printout the URI being called ?

Comment: console.log( URI goes here );